# How to display Formula(text) data type field as list in VF page

Tags: visualforce, custom-object, visualforce-component, custom-field

I have VF page which get a many text based on the text entered in the multi-picklist values. The field could return 3 or 4 sentence based on the condition I specified in for field which has a formula(Text) data type.

I want to display it as bulletin points in my page. I have the code in VF as:

```
<div id="container3" style="width:720px">
<p style="font-size:18px;">Objects:style="font-size:18px;"/></p>
<li><apex:outputText value="{!Page__c.Objects__c}" <li>
</div>
```

Objects__c is a Formula(text) and might return 3 values or 2 or 4  based on the formula condition that I specified.

With this I get output as :

- Circle Triangle Square Rectangle

However I need to get it like:

- Circle
- Triangle
- Square
- Rectangle

Each as a bullet point.

------edited ------

So I just recreated my problem into a simpler form, but people have asked to share the actual code, thus here is my code:

```
<apex:page standardController="Plan_Reviews__c" showHeader="false" extensions="BuildingProCertObjectionSheet" sidebar="true">
<apex:form >
<apex:image url="{!imageURL}" style="width:720px" ></apex:image>

 <apex:panelGrid columns="2" width="720px">

   <apex:panelGrid columns="2" width="60%">
   <h1 style="font-size:20px;"> PRO-CERT CHECKLIST</h1><br></br>
         <!--  <p style="font-size:18px;">FPIMS:</p> <apex:outputText value="{!Plan_Reviews__c.FPIMS__c}" style="font-size:18px;"/>-->

           <p style="font-size:18px;">Premise: <apex:outputText value="{!Plan_Reviews__c.Establishment_Address__c}" style="font-size:18px;"/></p>

   </apex:panelGrid>
   <apex:panelGrid columns="2" width="40%">         
           <p style="font-size:18px;">Date:<apex:outputText value="{!currentdate}" style="font-size:18px;"/></p>
   </apex:panelGrid>
   <apex:panelGrid columns="2" width="60%">
           <p style="font-size:18px;">DOB Job Number:</p><apex:outputText value="{!Plan_Reviews__c.DOB_Job_Number__c}" style="font-size:18px;"/>     
           <!--<p style="font-size:18px;">Name of Contractor:<apex:outputText value="{!Plan_Reviews__c.Contractor_Name__r.Name}" style="font-size:18px;"/></p>-->
   </apex:panelGrid>
</apex:panelGrid>  

<div id="container1" style="width:720px">
  <p  style="font-size:18px;">TO WHOM IT MAY CONCERN:</p>
  <p style="font-size:18px;">Plans submitted to this office have been examined and found to be unacceptable for an inspection and test at this time. The plan will be re-examined after the following defects are corrected:</p>
</div>

<div id="container2" style="width:720px">
 <apex:repeat value="{!objlist}" var="d">
    <tr>
    <td><apex:outputText value="{!d}" style="font-size:18px;" /></td><br></br>
    </tr>
 </apex:repeat>
</div>

<div id="container3" style="width:720px">

    <p style="font-size:18px;">Pro Cert Objection:</p>
     <li><apex:outputText value="{!Plan_Reviews__c.Pro_Cert_Objections_for_Letter__c}" style="font-size:18px;"/></li>
    <p style="font-size:18px;">Other Objection:<apex:outputText value="{!Plan_Reviews__c.Other_Violations__c}" style="font-size:18px;"/></p>
   <!-- <p style="font-size:18px;">By Order of Chief of Fire Prevention<br></br> 
    By&nbsp;<apex:outputText value="{!Plan_Reviews__c.Assigned_Reviewer_Title__c}"/>&nbsp;<apex:outputText value="{!Plan_Reviews__c.Assigned_Reviewer_s_Email__c}"/></p> -->
</div>

<apex:commandButton action="{!Savecopy}" disabled="false" value="Save"/>

</apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

I have  `Pro_Cert_Objections_for_Letter__c` as Formula(Text) and below is formula I use:

```
IF(INCLUDES(Pro_Cert_Objections__c, "Missing $210 FS PR Fee"), "Missing fire suppression plan review fee of $210.00 (to be paid at DOB borough office);", null) & 
IF(INCLUDES(Pro_Cert_Objections__c, "Missing TMR-2"), "Missing required TMR-2 application form;", null) & 
IF(INCLUDES(Pro_Cert_Objections__c, "TMR-2 missing FS contractor"), "Submitted TMR-2 application form does not identify registered fire suppression contractor;", null) &
```

So if the condition fails I get a null return and the null appears in new bullet point. I do not want a bullet point for NULL . How can I put only valid text in list and not NULL.

Comment: Can you update your question with your formula as well?

Comment: how do you separate items in Objects__c formula?

Comment: Please see the edit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it through javascript. Split the string and create a `<li>` list and add it to the page. Here is how you can do this.

```
<apex:page standardController="Book__c" showHeader="false" sidebar="false">
    <div id="container3" style="width:720px">
        <ul id="ul-test"></ul>
    </div>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var inputText = "{!Book__c.Objects__c}";
        console.log(inputText);
        var arrinputText = inputText.split(' '),
        ul = document.getElementById("ul-test");

        for (var i = 0, len = arrinputText.length; i < len; i++) {
            var li = document.createElement("li");
            var text = document.createTextNode(arrinputText[i]);
            li.appendChild(text);
            ul.appendChild(li);
        }       
    </script>   
</apex:page>
```

In this exaple `{!Book__c.Objects__c}` returns Circle Triangle Square Rectangle.

The out put is

- Circle
- Triangle
- Square
- Rectangle

**Updated code**

```
<apex:page standardController="Plan_Reviews__c" showHeader="false" extensions="BuildingProCertObjectionSheet" sidebar="true">
<apex:form >
<apex:image url="{!imageURL}" style="width:720px" ></apex:image>

 <apex:panelGrid columns="2" width="720px">

   <apex:panelGrid columns="2" width="60%">
   <h1 style="font-size:20px;"> PRO-CERT CHECKLIST</h1><br></br>
         <!--  <p style="font-size:18px;">FPIMS:</p> <apex:outputText value="{!Plan_Reviews__c.FPIMS__c}" style="font-size:18px;"/>-->

           <p style="font-size:18px;">Premise: <apex:outputText value="{!Plan_Reviews__c.Establishment_Address__c}" style="font-size:18px;"/></p>

   </apex:panelGrid>
   <apex:panelGrid columns="2" width="40%">         
           <p style="font-size:18px;">Date:<apex:outputText value="{!currentdate}" style="font-size:18px;"/></p>
   </apex:panelGrid>
   <apex:panelGrid columns="2" width="60%">
           <p style="font-size:18px;">DOB Job Number:</p><apex:outputText value="{!Plan_Reviews__c.DOB_Job_Number__c}" style="font-size:18px;"/>     
           <!--<p style="font-size:18px;">Name of Contractor:<apex:outputText value="{!Plan_Reviews__c.Contractor_Name__r.Name}" style="font-size:18px;"/></p>-->
   </apex:panelGrid>
</apex:panelGrid>  

<div id="container1" style="width:720px">
  <p  style="font-size:18px;">TO WHOM IT MAY CONCERN:</p>
  <p style="font-size:18px;">Plans submitted to this office have been examined and found to be unacceptable for an inspection and test at this time. The plan will be re-examined after the following defects are corrected:</p>
</div>

<div id="container2" style="width:720px">
 <apex:repeat value="{!objlist}" var="d">
    <tr>
    <td><apex:outputText value="{!d}" style="font-size:18px;" /></td><br></br>
    </tr>
 </apex:repeat>
</div>

<div id="container3" style="width:720px">

    <p style="font-size:18px;">Pro Cert Objection:</p>
    <ul id="ul-obj-letters" style="font-size:18px;"></ul>
    <p style="font-size:18px;">Other Objection:<apex:outputText value="{!Plan_Reviews__c.Other_Violations__c}" style="font-size:18px;"/></p>
   <!-- <p style="font-size:18px;">By Order of Chief of Fire Prevention<br></br> 
    By&nbsp;<apex:outputText value="{!Plan_Reviews__c.Assigned_Reviewer_Title__c}"/>&nbsp;<apex:outputText value="{!Plan_Reviews__c.Assigned_Reviewer_s_Email__c}"/></p> -->
</div>

<apex:commandButton action="{!Savecopy}" disabled="false" value="Save"/>

</apex:form>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var inputText = "{!Plan_Reviews__c.Pro_Cert_Objections_for_Letter__c}";
        console.log(inputText);
        var arrinputText = inputText.split(' '),
        ul = document.getElementById("ul-obj-letters");

        for (var i = 0, len = arrinputText.length; i < len; i++) {
            var li = document.createElement("li");
            var text = document.createTextNode(arrinputText[i]);
            li.appendChild(text);
            ul.appendChild(li);
        }       
    </script>
</apex:page>
```

Comment: Sorry , it did not work this way. I have sHowHeader="false" to make it view able in a new page tab. If I make it as true it appears on the salesforce interface itself.  I have this in <div id="container3" style="width:720px"> <ul id="ul-test"></ul></div>. Do I have to make any change to get element by id?

Comment: I have made `showHeader="false" sidebar="false"` and  `<div id="container3" style="width:720px">
  <ul id="ul-test"></ul>
 </div>` and it is working for me. I have updated the solution. Can you please update your question with complete VF page code?

Comment: Please see the edit. I have included my actual code in here.

Comment: I coul not find `apex:outputText value="{!Page__c.Objects__c}"`. Can you please let me know if `apex:outputText value="{!Plan_Reviews__c.Pro_Cert_Objections_for_Letter__c}"` is same?

Comment: I renamed Plan_Reviews__c.Pro_Cert_Objections_for_Letter__c to Page__c.Objects__c just renamed the variable names to suit the problem which I described. But actually the name is Plan_Reviews__c.Pro_Cert_Objections_for_Letter__c

Comment: Check the updated code. It should work. If not let me know the JavaScript error.

Comment: Thanks, It comes in bullet point but now each word of the text appears in a list, if I have a sentence - My name is RDVSM, it appears as 1. My 2.name 3.is 4.RDVSM

Comment: The comment is not visible please edit it.

Comment: Thanks I have to use - var arrinputText = inputText.split(';') , to split each sentence, else if I use space the sentence is broken down to words and displayed a list. Also I have problem dealing with NULL sentence, please see my edits in about question.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/29497/discussion-between-saroj-bera-and-rdvsm).

Comment: Are you available in discussion chat?

Comment: Used -  if(arrinputText[i]!== "") and worked fine Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<div id="container3" style="width:720px">
<p style="font-size:18px;">Objects:style="font-size:18px;"/></p>

    <apex:repeat value="{!Page__c.Objects__c}" var="string" id="theRepeat">

        <li><apex:outputText value="{!string}" id="theValue"/></li>

    </apex:repeat>

</div>
```

Comment: Sorry it did not work this way! I still get everything in one line

Comment: I think you should use a controller to get the value of Page__c.Objects__c and do the following:

String.split(Page__c.Objects__c, ' ')

It will return an array, then you should call the array in your VF Page. And replace the repeat value with your variable in your controller.